# IE7 CSS issues with grid layout

Tags: css

Can anyone help with the issue I have with the colour boxes on this page http://www.water-edge.co.uk/lamburngeeky/projects.html. The coloured boxes are supposed to align to the box but are being shunted to the right.

Other browsers are fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delete from `#container1` the `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0):

For starters, class "besps_slides_23_0" has position:absolute, but you provide no top or left coordinates, then you nest a div with this class inside itself. Your HTML is confusing and unnecessarily convoluted.

Another tip: never use wildcards in CSS (*). They are resource hogs.

You can accomplish everything you're doing here with a styled unordered list. A table may seem to make it simple, but it's not the answer.

See: `http://preview.moveable.com/jm/slideshow/`

Comment: if it has table structure why not use a table?

Comment: Tables are for tabluar data, not for layout.